# Циклическое заполнение placeholder'ов в таблице

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

Имеется таблица:

```
<h4 class="text-center">Матрица A</h4>
<table class="matrixA">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Необходимо заполнить placeholder'ы ячеек их соответствующими координатами (т.е. a1,1, a1,2 и т.д.). Как это реализовать?

Ссылка на codepen: http://codepen.io/ivan1fun/pen/dMZZYG

Comment: метод index() от   tr и td используйте как вариант.

Comment: Может это и не ответ, но на всякий случай http://matrixcalc.org/ считает матрицы, можешь посмотреть исходники, они там не сжаты

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.attr("placeholder", "a[" + $this.closest("td").index() + ", " + $this.closest("tr").index() + "]");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <caption>Матрица A</caption>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Премного благодарен! То, что надо :)